# How to fix Eclipse IDE Run Configuration (Problem occurred dialog)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I use Eclipse IDE(Spring Tool Suite) for many years, and periodically I have the same problem with the Launching project

The problem happens with the existing "Run Configuration" after time, maybe after the IDE update, but I unable to reproduce why this happens. To quick fix, I just remove "Run Configuration" with error, and just "mouse right-click on Application.java -> Run As -> Spring Boot App" and all work, but I need again add environment variables to this new configuration ... etc

I bored to have this problem for many years repeatedly from time to time.
I think other Eclipse or Spring STS users have the same problem/experience.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?
Except Delete and Create again "Run Configuration"...

[image]

Problem Occurred

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching Operational".
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject.getProject()" because "project" is null
```

[image]

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject.getProject()" because "project" is null
```

Comment: Something is wrong with the launch configuration, seems like it doesn't have a project relation. You can try to fix it by editing the config by explicitly selecting a project, or if you don't mind... the easiest is probably to just delete the 'broken' config and create a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Close Eclipse IDE
2. Go to your workspace directory e.g: workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches (for linux I use command "locate .launch" to quick find)
3. Find your broken Launching configuration in this directory, and open it with a text editor
4. Check these two lines is exist, if not exist, you must add these two lines with your 'value="web"' module name. If you don't know the module name, just create a new "Run Configuration" and find differences with the previous "Run Configuration" in the .launch file

```xml
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MODULE_NAME" value="web"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR" value="web"/>
```

After all, Run Eclipse IDE

Comment: Just changed "web" for my project name , as stated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Issue : this issue also happens in Mac compatible eclipse
[image]

Solution:

1. Find your workspace
   Open eclipse and navigate to Preferences -> General-> Workspace -> Show full workspace path:
2. Open in the workspace path in the File explorer(Windows) or Finder (Mac)
3. Navigate to -> .metadata -> .plugins -> org.eclipse.debug.core -> .launches ->  and open in text editor
4. Add an entry within the  like below:
   "/>
5. Save and Close the editor
6. Restart your eclipse/STS

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported the project which don't have target folder then do maven update and maven clean install.After that the run as-> spring boot app option will be available